# Why is my variable considered out of scope?

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

I am currently using Angular 9 and I am having some issues with accessing a global variable. I can access the listOfProjects variable when I pass an ES6 callback function to `map` but when I use a normal function I get an error saying that `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I think that the variable has gone out of scope. I am little bit lost regarding how to fix this. Also if you see any bad practices in my code please feel free to point them out as well as I am fairly new to angular.

The code with the normal function:

```
export class DataService {

  listOfProjects: Project[] = [];
  API_URL: string = "API_URL";
  homePageHeading: string; 

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getProjects() {
    this.listOfProjects.length = 0;

    this.httpClient.get<any[]>("API_URL").pipe(
    
    
    map(function mapData(res) {
      this.homePageHeading = res[0].heading

      res[0].projects.map( (project) =>  
            this.listOfProjects.push(
            { 
              "company": project.company,
              "description": project.description,
              "imageUrl": this.API_URL + project.image[0].url,
              "Link": project.Link
            }) 
          )
    })     
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(this.listOfProjects);
    });
  }
}
```

The code with the normal function:

```
export class DataService {

  listOfProjects: Project[] = [];
  API_URL: string = "API_URL";
  homePageHeading: string; 

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getProjects() {
    this.listOfProjects.length = 0;

    this.httpClient.get<any[]>("API_URL").pipe(
    
    
    map((res) => {
      this.homePageHeading = res[0].heading

      res[0].projects.map( (project) =>  
            this.listOfProjects.push(
            { 
              "company": project.company,
              "description": project.description,
              "imageUrl": this.API_URL + project.image[0].url,
              "Link": project.Link
            }) 
          )
    })     
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(this.listOfProjects);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Classic javascript `function`s define their own `this` context. If you specifically want to use normal function here, you can save outer `this` into a variable (like `this_`) before calling `map`. But I would advise just using context-free callback instead.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: you may want to use tap instead of map and inside of the function of tap, do the work you were trying to do with the res.projects.map.

Comment: @dmitryguzeev where about would you declare it? Because I am having an issue where I can't declare the variable inside of `getProjects` but I can declare it inside the `map` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @R.Richards I read through that and I understand what's going on now. But I am having an issue where I can't declare a variable with the `this` inside `getProjects()` but I can declare one inside the `map` function.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a classic function the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. It more or less looks at the object that is calling it to determine what is `this`.

Arrow functions look at the outer scope of the function to determine what `this` is.

So in your case, you want `this` to be the outer scope, meaning the DataService. So using arrow function ignores the object that is calling the function, but looking at where the function was defined for scope.

You can [read more here](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e#:%7E:text=Arrow%20functions%20are%20best%20for,of%20this%20in%20their%20scope.) for examples.